# Find the sum of amount between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following scenario:

There is a table that contains data loaded weekly and last day of the month for each customer and product.

I need to get the data sum for the data loaded on the last day of the month for each product (let's say) - that consolidates it for all the customers.

Input is 2 dates - start and end of the period and I need to get this done in a single SQL query.

Below is the query that I am using. Period is a datetime field.

```
SELECT      
        Period
        ,sum([Amount]) as 'Amount'
from        tableA 
 where  Period between convert(datetime,'201110'+'01',121) and dateadd(second,-1,dateadd(month,1,convert(datetime,'201201'+'01',121)))
   and  cond1 = .....
   and  cond2 = ....
group by    
        Period
```

The query above results in data as shown below.

[image]

I need to find out the amount on the last day of each month, i.e. one for 31-Oct-11, 30-Nov-11, 31-Dec-11 and so on.

The final result should look as below (as opposed to what I am getting currently - above):

[image]

Can you please help !!

Comment: We are using Sql Server 2008

Comment: Not sure I get what your desired result would look like. Could you please update the question with an example.

Comment: Updated with the desired result set. As mentioned, the data is loaded weekly and once at the month end. We need is the sum of amount for the last day of the month. The date range provided could be spread over a period of months. (Please see the sample query that I have posted - it contains the date provided in YYYYMM format).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the values for the last day of each month in the period I think adding a condition like this should work:

```
AND Period = DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, period) + 1, 0))
```

The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT
    Period,
    SUM([Amount]) AS 'Amount'
FROM tableA 
WHERE Period BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'201110'+'01',121) AND DATEADD(SECOND,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'201201'+'01',121)))
  AND Period = DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, period) + 1, 0))
  AND  cond1 = .....
  AND  cond2 = ....
GROUP BY Period
```

If your period datetime has a time value you will have to remove that part to get the match with the last day date that the condition provides like this:

```
AND DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Period), 0) = 
    DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, period) + 1, 0))
```

Comment: My guess is OP is looking for something like this moving the period to your `group by` clause: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a426/2

Comment: @sgeddes Maybe but I don't think so. The OP states that there are data loaded on the very last day of the month and the sample results doesn't seem to be a sum for the month but a discrete value for that specific day. But I could be wrong.

Comment: +1 -- actually rereading the question, I believe you are correct.

Comment: Thanks that was what I needed, that looked simple and I couldn't figure it out - may be lots of work..  Appreciate your help